# Redirect http xampp windows

Tags: http, xampp, redirect, http-redirect

I am running xampp on windows server and I want to redirect requests from my old url to the new one. I tried editing httpd-vhosts.conf with the following code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.urla.gr 
    Redirect  /www.urlb.gr
    </VirtualHost>
```

and when I tried URLA from my browser it redirected me to URLB but URLB was not responsive. Both domain names have the same A record (the xampp server in question)